# How should I read the filename in FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION struct

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, file-monitoring, readdirectorychangesw

I'm trying to monitor file changes but I am not really sure on how to read the filename in the FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION struct:

```
    HANDLE dwChangeHandles[2];
    DWORD dwWaitStatus;
    wChangeHandles[0] = FindFirstChangeNotification(dirname.c_str(), FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE);
    if (dwChangeHandles[0] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) printerr(__FILE__,__LINE__,"FindFirstChangeNotification function failed.\n");
    ...
    if ((dwChangeHandles[0] == NULL) || (dwChangeHandles[1] == NULL))  //final validation
        printerr(__FILE__,__LINE__,"Unexpected NULL from FindFirstChangeNotification.\n");

    while (TRUE) {
        std::cout << "Waiting for notification...\n";
        dwWaitStatus = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, dwChangeHandles, FALSE, INFINITE);
        if(dwWaitStatus==WAIT_OBJECT_0){
            std::cout << "Something changed\n";

            DWORD BytesReturned;
            size_t bufLen = 1024;
            FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION buffer[bufLen];
            if (ReadDirectoryChangesW(dwChangeHandles[0], buffer, bufLen, FALSE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, &BytesReturned, NULL, NULL)){
                std::wcout << std::wstring(buffer->FileName)<< std::endl; //THERE IS NOTHING IN THE EXPECTED OUTPUT HERE
            }
            if (FindNextChangeNotification(dwChangeHandles[0]) == FALSE ) printerr(__FILE__,__LINE__,"FindNextChangeNotification function failed.\n");
        }

        else if(dwWaitStatus==WAIT_TIMEOUT) printerr(__FILE__,__LINE__,"No changes in the timeout period.\n");
        else printerr(__FILE__,__LINE__,"Unhandled dwWaitStatus.\n");
    }
```

Is there something I am doing wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a number of problems that I can see immediately:

1. According to the docs for the [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function, the buffer needs to be `DWORD`-aligned. As you are using a buffer on the stack this isn't guaranteed - you should allocate one from the heap instead.
2. You don't seem to be using the function correctly. Normally you would call `ReadDirectoryChangesW` first, and **then** wait on the event. Not the other way around. When `ReadDirectoryChangesW` returns for an asynchronous call there is usually no data in the buffer at that point. You need to wait for notification that the request has been completed before using the buffer contents.
3. `FindNextChangeNotification` is only used with `FindFirstChangeNotification`, so this is completely wrong. When the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` completes you need to use the `NextEntryOffset` field in the [`FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) structure to loop through the returned events.

**Edit**: Since you've added more code to your question it's now obvious that you are mixing the two APIs. `FindFirstChangeNotification` and `FindNextChangeNotification` are one API, and `ReadDirectoryChangesW` is another. I believe you've been confused by this passage in the docs:

> This function does not indicate the change that satisfied the wait
>   condition. To retrieve information about the specific change as part
>   of the notification, use the ReadDirectoryChangesW function.

I guess your confusion is understandable, but the two APIs can't be used together. If you're using `FindFirstChangeNotification` then all you get is a notification that *something* changed, and you have to re-read the directory to find out what it was. If you want specific notifications at the file level then you have to use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to do the monitoring.

Comment: Well I was using the handle returned by FindFirstChangeNotification since I read somewhere that it was valid to specific info of the event using ReadDirectoryChangesW

Comment: @shuji No the two functions are completely different. The handle you give to `ReadDirectoryChangesW` needs to come from `CreateFile`.

Comment: Yes I just tried that and worked fine, thank you bro.

Comment: Memory alignment is a feature of an object type. The alignment for an object does not change when allocated on the stack or the free store.